# Evaluating $\cos1°\cos2°\cos3°\cdots\cos89°$

Tags: trigonometry

I was solving a question and got struck in a sub-question which is,

> If
>   $$x=\cos1°\cos2°\cos3°\cdots\cos89°$$
>   Find the value of $x$.

I don't actually have any idea on how to proceed on this question. Any hints are welcome.
The answer given in the book is a perfect integer $17$

Comment: Do you know $\cos(x) \cos(y) = \frac{\cos(x + y) + \cos(x - y)}{2}$?

Comment: Hint: Take note of the $44$ incidences of $\cos x\cos y$ where $x+y=90^\circ$

Comment: Yup,I do about this

Comment: @user170231 This didn't really work for me.  Please look at my answer.  Is there something I'm overlooking or doing wrong?

Comment: This question IS NOT DUPLICATE. It is not the same to multiply 89 times $x_i$ that multiply 89 times $\sqrt{1-x_i^2}$

Comment: @Piquito $x=\cos1°\cos2°\cos3°\cdots\cos89°=\cos(90-89)°\cos(90-88)°\cos(90-87)°\cdots\cos(90-1)°=\sin89°\sin88°\sin87°\cdots\sin1°$. How is it not a duplicate?

Comment: @YuiTo Cheng: You are right! I was wrong. Then for $|x_i|\le 1$ we have from my error an equality not trivial I feel (it is maybe trivial but i don't see at first glance the triviality.

Comment: I request you to reopen the question

Answer (score 3):

I tried the method suggested in the comments, but it seems to bog down.

$$\begin{align}
I&=\prod_{k=1}^{89}\cos{k^\circ}\\
&=\cos{45^\circ}\prod_{k=1}^{44}\cos{k^\circ}\prod_{k=46}^{89}\cos{k^\circ}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\prod_{k=1}^{44}\cos{k^\circ}\cos(90-k)^\circ\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\prod_{k=1}^{44}\frac12(\cos90^\circ+\cos(90-2k)^\circ)\\
&=\frac1{2^{44}\sqrt2}\prod_{k=1}^{44}\cos(90-2k)^\circ\\
&=\frac1{2^{44}\sqrt2}\prod_{k=1}^{22}\cos(90-2k)^\circ\prod_{k=23}^{44}\cos(90-2k)^\circ\\
&=\frac1{2^{44}\sqrt2}\prod_{k=1}^{22}\frac12(\cos90^\circ+\cos(90-4k)^\circ)\\
&=\frac1{2^{66}\sqrt2}\prod_{k=1}^{22}\cos(90-4k)^\circ
\end{align}$$
and now we can no longer group the arguments in pairs that add up to $90^\circ.$  At the next stage, if I follow the strategy of grouping the largest arguments with the smallest, I get $$
\frac1{2^{77}\sqrt2}\prod_{k=1}^{11}(\cos88^\circ+\cos(92-8k)^\circ),$$ which is better than what we started with, but still unpleasant.

I think it might be better to approximate the product as follows.

$$\begin{align}
\log I&=\sum_{k=0}^{90}\log(\cos k^\circ)\\
&\approx \int_0^{90}\log\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{180}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\cos u\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}$$

It is [known](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-integrate-log-cos-x-from-0-to-pi-2) that $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\cos u\mathrm{d}u=-\frac{\pi\log2}{2},$$ so we get $$\log I \approx -90\log2$$ and $$I\approx2^{-90}.$$

One can use the known error estimate in the trapezoidal rule to bound the error in this estimate, but I haven't done that.

**NOTES**

This may not be a very good estimate, at least in terms of relative error.  A simple-minded python script gives $$I\approx 2^{-85.75}.$$  Also, if we're going to approximate it, we could just say $\cos88^\circ\approx0$ and forge ahead.

**P.S.**

Whoops.  The derivative of $\log\cos x$ is $-\tan x$, so bounding the error with the trapezoidal rule, or the Euler-Maclaurin formula won't be easy.

Comment: Full disclosure, I didn't look any further into the suggestion I provided; I just happened to recall this being a usual "trick" for finding identities involving products of sines/cosines (case in point being the linked duplicate post). Had I done the legwork myself, I would have gotten to$$\frac1{2^{44}\sqrt2}\prod_{k=1}^{44}\cos\frac{2k\pi}{180}=\frac1{2^{44}\sqrt2}\prod_{k=1}^{44}\cos\frac{k\pi}{90}$$then consider looking for some way to condense the product of the first $44$ $90^{\rm th}$ roots of unity.

Comment: Actually the answer is 17

Comment: Please vote to reopen this question, I have found a marvellous answer for it

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-One has $$x=\cos1°\cos2°\cos3°\cdots\cos89°\\ \frac{2x}{\sqrt2}=(\cos1°\cos2°\cdots \cos44°)(\cos46°\cos47°\cdots\cos89^o)\space\space..... (88\text{ factors})$$ and because of $\cos(x)\cos(90-x)=\dfrac{\sin(2x)}{2}$
$$\frac{2^{45}x}{\sqrt2}=(\sin2^o\sin4^o\sin6^o\cdots\sin88^o)\space\space..... (44\text{ factors})$$ Again, because of $\sin(x)\sin(90-x)=\dfrac{\sin(2x)}{2}$
$$\frac{2^{45+22
}x}{\sqrt2}=(\sin4^o\sin8^o\sin12^o\cdots\sin84^o\sin88^o)\space\space..... (22\text{ factors})$$There must certainly be several elementary ways (without the use of Multiplier Angle Formulas) reducing the number of factors. For example we can reduce to $11$ factors to determine with calculator as follows:

$$\sin4^o\cos2^o\approx0.0697\\\sin8^o\cos6^o\approx0.1384\\ \sin12^o\cos10^o\approx0.2047\\\sin16^o\cos14^o\approx0.2674\\\sin20^o\cos18^o\approx0.3252\\\sin24^o\cos22^o\approx0.3771\\\sin28^o\cos26^o\approx0.4219\\\sin32^o\cos30^o\approx0.4589\\\sin36^o\cos34^o\approx0.4872\\\sin40^o\cos38^o\approx0.5065\\\sin44^o\cos42^o\approx0.5162$$Thus we have
$$x\approx\dfrac{0.00155969\sqrt2}{2^{67}}$$